# How do I list the indexes of a table with its corresponding column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Say I have table A. How do I lookup the indexes of column A.
Then what is the syntax for referring to that index in a SELECT statement query?

Thank you

Comment: What did you try? did look at _sys.indexes_ and _sys.index_columns_?

Comment: No i didint try that, would that give me the indexes of all databases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SELECT` statement does not refer to an index (unless you explicitly give an optimization hint, which is unusual).  That is, the index is hidden, just part of the database.  It is used by the optimizer, when the optimizer calculates that the best query plan would use the index.

So, it is sort of "set-it-and-forget-it".

You can look up what indexes are available using the system tables/views.  I would recommend starting with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES`.

Comment: So if i understand, it is only used during the setting up of tables ?

Comment: @Ismafoot . . . Not at all.  It is used in any query where the optimizer "thinks" it should be used.  You only need to create an index once.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You can use hints in SQL Server like `WITH (INDEX(...))` but I have always interpreted this as "I'm smarter than the optimizer" when in reality, you're not.

Comment: @DStanley . . . I was debating on whether to put that in, but since you mention it I added verbiage so the answer is not "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

You can find information in system tables sys.indexes, sys.index_columns and sys.columns.
If you want to find specific index on table A that uses column A you can use below query

```
select distinct i.name, STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + col.name

                                FROM    sys.indexes ind_col
                                    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ind_col_detail
                                            ON ind_col.object_id = ind_col_detail.object_id
                                            AND ind_col.index_id = ind_col_detail.index_id
                                            INNER JOIN sys.columns col
                                            ON i.object_id = col.object_id
                                            AND ind_col_detail.column_id = col.column_id
                                WHERE   i.object_id = ind_col.object_id
                                            AND i.index_id = ind_col.index_id
                                            AND ind_col_detail.is_included_column = 0
                                ORDER BY ind_col_detail.key_ordinal
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS key_column_list ,
                                STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + col.name

                                FROM    sys.indexes ind_col
                                    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ind_col_detail
                                            ON ind_col.object_id = ind_col_detail.object_id
                                            AND ind_col.index_id = ind_col_detail.index_id
                                            INNER JOIN sys.columns col
                                            ON i.object_id = col.object_id
                                            AND ind_col_detail.column_id = col.column_id
                                WHERE   i.object_id = ind_col.object_id
                                            AND i.index_id = ind_col.index_id
                                            AND ind_col_detail.is_included_column = 1
                                ORDER BY ind_col_detail.key_ordinal
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS included_column_list
                                from sys.indexes i
inner join sys.index_columns ic
on i.index_id = ic.index_id
and i.object_id = ic.object_id
and OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) = 'Table A'
inner join sys.columns c
on c.column_id = ic.column_id
and c.object_id = i.object_id 
and c.name = 'Column A'
```

The query returns an index even if the column A is included column. More details about included column is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-2017)

In general SQL server optimizer calculates the best plan for your query and decides if  an index will be or not used while a query is executed.

But there is an option to force SQL server optimizer to use specific index using table hint INDEX.

Microsoft documentation about table hints is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2016)

And an example how hint can be used by Pinal Dave is [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/08/sql-server-introduction-to-force-index-query-hints-index-hint-part2/)

Comment: I'll just point out that all of the `FOR XML PATH` noise is just to get all of the columns on one line, when most reporting/display can do this for you without mucking up the query.